# SwiftUI how to align the navigation bar title on center when user taps on a navigation link?

Tags: swiftui

I have a TabView in a struct. I add a NavigationView and a NavigationLink. When the view shows up the navigation bar is centered. When i tap on the navigation link the text is on the leading side. How can i make the navigation bar text align to center after i tap the navigation link in iOS 16 and above? I have searched stackoverflow and nothing seems to work in iOS 16 with this specific implementation i am posting below. Any help appreciated.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

public struct TabViewTest: View {

 @State var selectedTab: Int = 0
    
    public var body: some View {
        
        TabView (selection: $selectedTab) {
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("destination"))
                {
                    FeedView(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
                        .navigationBarTitle("Feed", displayMode: .inline)
                        .toolbar {
                            ToolbarItemGroup {
                                Image(systemName :"magnifyingglass.circle")
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        selectedTab = 1
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            .tabItem {
                Text("Feed")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            .tag(0)

}
}


struct ProfileView: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white.ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Text("Nav link test tap anywhere")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using your whole FeedView as the label for the navigation link. Is this intentional?

Comment: @mucahid-erdogan yes just for testing